# Correlation value not capturing for custom string as Left Boundary

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am capturing a string as my Left Boundary (LB) and then dividing that LB into 3 parts with strcpy and putting the value in char MyString. When I play my script, the correlation is not getting captured.

char MyString is capturing the value correctly, as when I'm printing it with lr_output_message it is showing me the correct LB as is from the server response values.

This is exactly what I'm doing...

```c
char MyString[9999];

// original LB value is LB=DesktopQueuedActivitiesLV:0:CreateDate\" label=\"Create Date\" value=\"",

for (i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i++) {
    lr_save_int(i,"MyRow");
    strcpy(MyString, "DesktopQueuedActivitiesLV:");
    strcat(MyString, lr_eval_string("{MyRow}"));
    strcat(MyString, ":CreateDate\\\" label=\\\"Create Date\\\" value=\\\"");

    lr_output_message("MyString = %s",MyString);

    web_reg_save_param("DateReceived",
    lr_eval_string("LB={MyString}"),      
    "RB=\">", 
    "Ord=1",
    LAST);
}
```

Upon replay can't find the value for DateReceived

If I replace the line `lr_eval_string("LB={MyString}")` with the actual LB value, then it is working. Also, the `lr_output_message("MyString = %s",MyString);` is printing the exact same original LB value.

Can't figure it out why MyString is capturing the correct value but can't replace during actual line when playing the `web_reg_save_param("DateReceived",`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a loadrunner parameter designation for a C parameter inside of a loop.   Both the loadrunner parameter reference is odd here, as is a re-running of the same correlation statement multiple times, as only the last one would have an affect when executed.

```
lr_output_message("MyString = %s",MyString);

web_reg_save_param("DateReceived",
lr_eval_string("LB={MyString}"),
```

Notice, the lr_output_message() is treating MyString as a C variable, but the second parameter of the web_reg_save_param() is treating the same element as a LoadRunner parameter.   You either need to convert the C string to a LoadRunner parameter, recommend a different name, such as LR_MyString to differentiate the C string from the LR Parameter or create a C parameter which is in the form of "LB=myleftboundary"

```
lr_output_message("MyString = %s",MyString);
lr_save_string(MyString, "LR_MyString");

web_reg_save_param("DateReceived",
lr_eval_string("LB={LR_MyString}"),
```

OR

```
strcpy(MyString, "LB=DesktopQueuedActivitiesLV:");
strcat(MyString, lr_eval_string("{MyRow}"));
strcat(MyString, ":CreateDate\\\" label=\\\"Create Date\\\" value=\\\"");

lr_output_message("MyString = %s",MyString);

web_reg_save_param("DateReceived",
MyString,
```

You appear to be on the path of creating a psuedo array with DateReceived due to the loop which is executing once in this test, but you are probably wanting to increase the number of loop entries.   In this case you are likely to fail for any number of array elements greater than 1 as you will always have the last time executed as the fulfilled correlation.